# Guidance in the integration of solr with mahout

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, mahout

Please provide me the link for integration of mahout and solr. and also why these two things are to be integrated and how they work. Please guide me as im new to mahout and i know about solr quite well. My team lead has told me to integrate these two but i have no idea how and why

please do help me

Answer (score 2):

Mahout is a machine learning library, and can help build recommendations.

An example use case would be, build recommendations based on Solr searches. [This project](https://github.com/pferrel/solr-recommender%29) is an example of how Mahout can be used to build recommendations using an item-similarity matrix.

It is hard to guess the reason by just "integrate solr with mahout", you need to get more details on the actual requirements. But there are several algorithms in Mahout that you can use to build machine learning capabilities in your system using Solr's log / data as the training set.

**edit**
Solr Mahout integration - an old, but relevant [article](http://searchhub.org/2010/03/16/integrating-apache-mahout-with-apache-lucene-and-solr-part-i-of-3)  by Grant Ingersol.

list of Mahout algorthms - https://mahout.apache.org/users/basics/algorithms.html

Collaborative filtering algorithms may be of interest to you, for building recommendations.

Comment: two quick questions: * provide the link to integrate solr with mahout(great help)? and * which are those several algorithms

Comment: i followed the above "aritcle" im unable to hook into solr system.. i mean lucene.vector is not getting executed. I also passed print.sh(just echo "hello") instead of lucene.vector.. then also its not getting called.. im giving relative path as mentioned in the wiki https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UpdateHandlers+in+SolrConfig. please guide me